# python delete contents of a folder except folders with a specific name

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python... I've read up and it looks like I need to use glob - I just don't understand the filter process.

Imagine a directory structure like:

Main Directory
 - Sub-Directory to delete
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Alpha
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Bravo Keep
            file a
            file b
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Charlie
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Oscar Keep
            file a
            file b

Using Python how can I delete all the folders and their contents under the folder named "Main Directory" except if the folder name contains a string - in this example "Keep" so that it ends up like this and keeps the original directory structure.

Main Directory
 - Sub-Directory
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Bravo Keep
            file a
            file b
      - Sub-Sub-Directory Oscar Keep
            file a
            file b

Comment: Since you have no code, here's a no-code answer ;) *go through all directories and delete only those you wish to delete*.

Comment: ha sorry my fault I should have explained I'm trying to edit a kodi addon - nice answer though!!

Comment: this is the code as it stands, which is deleting all contents def Destroy_Path(path):
 shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `os.walk` or `os.path.listdir` to find out which directories exist. Then decide which to delete.

As a general rule, you shoud go through the documentation and see what functions exist when you want to do something. For OS functions see documentation for [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

**EDIT**

`shutil.rmtree` is used for deleting a folder with all of it's contents, which is quite useful if that is what you need, but in this case you need to use the lower-level API.